# What is a word that means "pushed" that has a negative (specifically angry) connotation?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice, writing

I am writing a book and currently have a scene where there are two people – one is sitting on the ground, and one is laying on a mattress next to them before *pushing* himself up to respond to the other's question.

For clarification, when I say "pushed himself up", I mean he just sat up.
How would I describe this in a way that would make him seem angry/annoyed?

Comment: When used to describe actions between people, "shoved" is often used in sense to mean "aggressively pushed".

Comment: By "pushing himself up," do you just mean that he sat up? Or stood up?

Comment: Yes, he just sat up, sorry for the confusion!

Comment: One problem is that a sentence like *He shoved himself up* which suggests anger, does not imply sitting up, but more suggests standing up. You will probably need something longer, which might not be such a bad thing in a book-length work.

Comment: **Lying** on a mattress! Possibly "He jerked up into a sitting position"?

Comment: He could *jump to his feet* depending on how far up he gets? That expression often suggests sudden emotion, although not necessarily anger. Is he standing or just lifting his head a bit?

Comment: You could use an adverb to qualify *how* he sat up. Even a neutral word, followed by another action. "He sat up quickly and glared at her".

Comment: He _thrust_ himself upright.  He _thrust_ himself into a sitting position.

Comment: Surged, Rocketed, Whipped, Launched, Sprung.  We're well into artistic interpretation here though.  The act being done in anger suggests speed.

Comment: In any scenario, what verbs do you think describe short, sharp movement that might express anger or annoyance?
Which would not lose their clarity in the reflexive sense of pushing himself?

By the by, neither of your pair could ever be ‘on a mattress next to them…’. No-one is ‘laying’ on a mattress except in the sense, unlikely here, of  ‘laying on a mattress to be placed next to them…’ meaning ‘arranging (for)…’

One lying ‘on a mattress before (anything)’ would be unusual.
‘… until pushing’; more likely, ‘…until he pushed’ would be more likely.

Answer (score 1):

One possibility might be [**snap**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/snap), in the sense of

> to move briskly or sharply

I think this provides the desired negative connotation because it plays on another definition of the word "snap":

> to utter sharp biting words : bark out irritable or peevish retorts.

Comment: Hello, qoheleth. Welcome to ELU. Though 'snap' (in the 'jerk' context) suggests briskness and  a cracking noise before testiness to me, I like your ' the desired ... connotation because it plays on another definition of the word W'.

Answer (score 0):

From [the full OED...](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/189183?rskey=TxTdUv&result=5&isAdvanced=false#eid)

> **start**
> 2a intransitive verb
> ***To move with a bound or sudden impulse from a position of rest or repose***
> Most recent citation:
> 2002   S. Waters Fingersmith xvi. 620
> *My voice made a dozen black birds start out of the bushes and fly off, cawing.*

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't specifically relate to *anger,* but you could say that he **bolted upright.** [TFD defines this as:](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/bolt+upright)

> To suddenly sit or stand up from a reclining position.